# Fetch username relative to user uid from firebase to display comments

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I'm creating collection view that holds the comments, where I am fetching the comments, comment id, post id, and user uid from Firebase. When I try and fetch the user details related to the user uid, and append the comments, it doesn't work. I think it's because I'm appending the snapshot.value inside the user reference and it therefore does not have the comment reference anymore. How do I fetch both the comment, and the username related to the UID and display it in the comments collection view?

Here's what the hierarchy in Firebase looks like:
[Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9td9Y.png)

In my view post controller, i'm fetching the comments like this.

```
  var comments = [Comment]()
fileprivate func fetchComments() {
    guard let postID = self.post?.id else {return}
    let commentRef = Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postID)
    commentRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}

        guard let uid = dict["uid"] as? String else {return}

        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)/profile")
        userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            if (snapshot.value as? [String: Any]) != nil {
                //let snap = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                var comment = Comment(dictionary: dict)


                comment.user = snapshot.value as? User
                self.comments.append(comment)
                print(comment)
                self.commentCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })

        })
}
```

Setting up the collection view for the comments like this.

```
extension ViewPostViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCollectionViewCell
    cell.comment = self.comments[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
}
```

My CommentsCollectionViewCell.swift has this code:

```
class CommentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var commentLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timePostedLabel: UILabel!

var comment: Comment? {
    didSet {
        guard let comment = comment else {return}
        guard let username = comment.user?.username else {return}
        print(username)
        commentLabel.text = comment.comment
        usernameLabel.text = comment.user?.username
    }
}
}
```

The comments model class has this code:

```
struct Comment {

var user: User?

let comment: String

let uid: String

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.comment = dictionary["comment"] as? String ?? ""
    self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
}
}
```

Comment: After reading this again I realized I misunderstood your question and have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would refactor your code to include the username in with the comment bucket to save you the load of work on the device to pull it from multiple sources later.

That would be pretty easy to fix. Add one or two lines of code to your `saveToFirebase` function and one or two lines of code to your `fetchComments` function.

But if you want to keep it the way it's structured, I would do something like:

```
func getComments(_ post: String, completion:  @escaping (_ info: [String?], _ error: NSError?) -> Void)  { 
    Database.database().reference.child("comments").child(postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                if let dict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    completion([dict["comment"],dict["uid"]],nil) // send data through handler
                } else { completion([], someError) }
            }
        } else { completion([], someError) }
    }
}


func getUserName(_ uid: String, completion:  @escaping (_ info: [String: Any]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)  { 
    Database.database().reference.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        completion([snapshot],nil) // send data back
    } 
}
```

Then inside of your collectionView when you are setting the content you could call the funtions like this:

```
        // or wherever you get your postID's from
getComments(posts[indexPath.row], completion: { (info, err) in 
    if err != nil { 
        print(err!.localizedDescription) 
    } else { 
        // info is available find user
        guard let uid = info[1] as? String? else { return }
        // do whatever else you want to with the info here 
        // like populate cell data (perform on main thread)
        getUserName(uid, completion: { (snapDict, err) in
            if err != nil {
                // handle error
            } else {
                // get Username from dictionary and do what you want with it
        }) // end getUserName
    } 
}) // end getComments
```